# using numpay array I coundn't show result

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, dataset, data-science

Hi guys I'm using python jupyter notebook 
I found difcult to make loop and show the result like below 
wordsList & wordFeel are 1d array 
the wordsListFeel is 2d array which is contain wordsList & wordFeel 
I want to check in which wordFeel belong to wordsList then combine them together to show me wordsListFeel

I'm using numpay array

```
wordsList:(['4362', 'bad', '1843','worse','1235','good','1141','better'])
wordFeel:(['better','872884','FFA401','worse','322','4A688C','better','240423','004E6F','good','199726','017E94'])
x = 2
y = 1
for wordFeel[x] in wordsList:
    print(wordsList[y], wordFeel[x])
    x += 3
    y = 2

result :
    wordsListFeel ([['4362','bad','4A688C']
                ['1843','worse','FFA401']
                ['1235','good','017E94']
                ['1141','better','004E6F']])
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? `for wordFeel[x] in wordsList` makes no sense to me

Comment: I tried many different ways to make it like the result but I couldn't 
do you have a solution to make the result like above ?

Comment: please check it again I added some information

Comment: Still dont get the idea here, for example why the 3rd element of the first row in your `wordsListFeel` is `4A688C` when the 1st and 2nd is `4362` and `bad` then? Do you give more info so we can see the logic clearer?

Comment: the wordsListFeel  array should contain in every 2 elements in the wordsList one element in wordFeel which is the 3rd, 6th, 9th or 12th element but should check if 'worse' in wordsList  should take the 6th element in wordFeel then check 'better' in wordsList and wordFeel so it should take 3rd element then so on.
Helpfully I made it clear

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you append (wordsList[y], wordFeel[x]) instead of printing it, and then you print that in the end, it would be better. I could give a better answer if you explained this a bit more.

Comment: I need to the result similar with above the 'for loop' I couldn't use it well 
if you have another way to make the result at the same above without loop it is ok